# Update hash file when rechecking files

Tags: hashsum

I'm currently saving each folder on a hash file with the following code

```
find folder/ -type f -exec sha256sum {} > checksumfolder.txt \;
```

I'm wondering if it is possible instead of checking/recalculating and recreating that txt file to just update the old txt file and add the newly added files that got no hash?

Answer (score 0):

Create a `Makefile` with the following contents:

```
SHAS := $(patsubst folder/%, sha/%, $(shell find folder/ -type f))

all: sha $(SHAS) checksumfolder.txt

sha:
    mkdir sha

sha/%: folder/%
    sha256sum $< > $@

checksumfolder.txt: $(SHAS)
    cat $(SHAS) > checksumfolder.txt
```

When you now run `make` inside the parent directory of `folder/`, a new `sha/` directory will be created containing the sha256sum of each file in `folder/`. At the end we concatenate all files into `checksumfolder.txt`.

When you run `make` a second time, nothing will be done.

When you touch a file in `folder/` or create a new one and run `make` the sha256sum of this specific file gets updated.

To learn more about `make` run `info make`.

---

If you never change a file (only add new ones), you could simply remember the file name with the most recent modification time when you last ran the `find` command and select only the newer files with:

```
find -newer REFERENCE_FILE
```

… or a direct timestamp (see date(1) DATE STRING) with

```
find -newermt TIME_STAMP
```